# How to get currentTime from audio player?

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio, mediaelement.js

I am using mediaelement.js as an audio player. How to get currentTime from player?

```js
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player audio');
player.play();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/2.18.1/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/2.18.1/mediaelementplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="player">

  <audio type="audio/mp3" controls="controls">
    <Source src="http://mediaelementjs.com/media/AirReview-Landmarks-02-ChasingCorporate.mp3"></Source>
  </audio>

</div>
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902306/mediaelement-js-video-player-display-time-based-on-outside-data

Comment: But this solution not working with flash i mean not working on opera.

Answer (score 0):

You can find lot of informations here :

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

```
player.currentTime;
```

Comment: currentTime not working with flash.